# Which are the Android embedded APIs?

Tags: android, android-embedded-api

I know on the core Android API there's some embedded third-part APIs such as Apache HTTP.

My question is: What else are embedded on the API also?

Comment: These are the dependencies of the android core, not sure if this covers all http://grepcode.com/static/data/html/repository.grepcode.com$java$ext/com.google.android$android/2.3.4_r1/visualization.svg

Comment: Well, this helps a bit, tell it as an answer and I'll make a up for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html:

1. Apache HTTP.
2. JSON: http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/package-summary.html
3. XML PULL: http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/package-summary.html